# Resizing an image to look the same across all devices

Tags: android, resources, imageview, drawable, adt

I read the http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and I understood only a few things.
So, I have an ImageView with `android:src = "@drawable/logo"`. The logo.png is placed inside my `res/drawable-mdpi` and its `image-size` is 100x100 pixels.

In what dimensions should I save the image in the following folders, so it can look the same in relation to the screen size across all devices?:

-`res/drawable-ldpi`
-`res/drawable-hdpi`
-`res/drawable-xhdpi`
-`res/drawable-xxhdpi`

Simple things. Is 75x75, 150x150, 200x200, 300x300, the correct answer? Should I bother changing its pixels/inch in my image editor as well?

Comment: By the way, where does this `xxhdpi` come from? It's not mentioned on http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html or is it?

Comment: I downloaded the latest Eclipse + Android Tools, and I get an xxhdpi folder as well, when I create a new Project. No it is not mentioned in the guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic numbers are 3:4:6:8:12. Those are the proportions you should use for l:m:h:xh:xxh -dpi image resources. For example, your launcher icon should be

- 36x36 for ldpi
- 48x48 for mdpi
- 72x72 for hdpi
- 96x96 for xhdpi
- 144x144 for xxhdpi

Comment: Thanks. What about the resolution? The pixels/inch parameter I get on Photoshop. Should it be changed as well? And if yes, how much?

Comment: That only affects its appearance in Photoshop, does it not?

Comment: if I increase the image size and not the resolution, from let's say, ldpi to xxhdpi, it looks ugly. Pixels are visible. Point is, that I don't know how much to decrease or increase it, does the 3:4:6:8:!2 rule apply as well?

Comment: That's what always happens when you take a small image and scale it up, the software has to up-sample and fill in more pixels. Generally I start with a larger image and work down. Use vector-based objects as much as possible. In some cases you may have to clean up or do some finer work on different sizes to make each look good (I'm not a designer, but that's what I see ours do sometimes).

Comment: Where is `xxhdpi` specified? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Class Stacker: I saw it mentioned somewhere but unfortunately I do not have a formal reference. You can confirm the proportions by comparing the launcher icons that are generated automatically when you create a new Android project in Eclipse.